# Converting the result type of string-join to NodeList

Tags: xml, string, xpath, jaxp, nodelist

I need to deal with legacy code which evaluates XPath expressions expects the results to resolve to NodeList. The code uses NodeList to identify how many nodes are selected by the XPath expression. The code proceeds only if one node is selected.

Now I need to use string-join function which return type is String. Is there any way to convert String to NodeList using another XPath function? Ideally, it will convert the String to a NodeList with one element which text content would be the String value. I tried with exsl:node-set() but with no success (Saxon-HE processor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to convert String to NodeList using another XPath
>   function?

**No, XPath is just a query language for XML documents -- it doesn't create nodes**.

If the legacy code expects the XPath expression to evaluate to a NodeList and the result of evaluationg your XPath expression is just a string, then to reuse that legacy code without writing new code, you must change your XPath expression, so that it selects one or more nodes.

Or, write your own code that uses the result of the evaluation of the XPath expression.

Comment: I guess there is no alternative of string-join function that concatenates elements and returns a NodeList which first element is the result. Otherwise, it would be awkward. I will stick to changing the code as I described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

XPath (even 2.0) can't create new nodes, for that you need XQuery or XSLT. Saxon supports both so you have the choice.

Comment: Can you show me some examples in the context of the issue, please?

Comment: I can help you with XSLT if you show me the input you have and the output you want. I am not familiar enough with JAXP to advice you on that. Saxon comes with a good documentation http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/embedding.xml so you might want to start there.

Comment: Well, the XPath expressions are used outside XSL context. They are read from a document (which includes different kind of scripts) and evaluated using JAXP (XPathFactory, XPath, XPathExpression and etc.). What about saxon:node-set()/exsl:node-set()? Do I need Saxon-EE to work with them?

Comment: exsl:node-set takes a result tree fragment (which you could only get as the result of XSLT anyway, not with pure XPath) and converts it into a node-set. It is not helpful to create nodes from primitive values.

Comment: I understand. It seems that I will need to change the code anyway. I was thinking of evaluating the XPath expression as a NodeList first, if there is an exception, I will try to evaluate it like a String. If still there is an exception it means that there is a problem with the XPath expression itself and will propagate the exception to the respective handler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting a Java layer around the Saxon XPath API, and doing the string-to-NodeList conversion in this Java layer. Your Java layer can implement the JAXP XPath interface and thus "pretend" to be the real XPath engine.